# Is there a standard notation for the multiplicative group generated by the primes $p\in P$?

Tags: group-theory, notation

Is there a standard notation for the multiplicative group generated by the primes $p\in P$?

Let $P$ be some set of primes e.g. $P=\{2,3\}$

Then $G_P$ is the multiplicative group generated by these primes so e.g. $G_{\{2,3\}}$ is the 3-smooth numbers and their inverses, with multiplication.

Is there a standard notation or way of expressing this group and similar?

Comment: Up to isomorphism this group is just a product of $|P|$ copies of $(\Bbb{Z}, 0, +)$, so one standard notation would be $\Bbb{Z}^{|P|}$..

Comment: @RobArthan coolio, thanks. I was wrestling with $\{2,3\}^{<\omega}$ and I knew it was wrong because in that, the orders of the sequences of primes would matter-  but I couldn't get it straight but yours makes total sense.

Comment: @RobArthan yes, please do.

Comment: I've posted an answer with a bit of extra discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $P = \{2, 3\}$ the elements of $G_P$ have a unique representation of the form $2^i3^j$ for $i, j \in \Bbb{Z}$ and this is easily checked to give an isomorphism between $G_P$ and the sum $\Bbb{Z}^2$ of two copies of the additive group of integers. In general, up to isomorphism, $G_P$ depends only on the cardinality $|P|$ of $P$, so one standard notation for $G_P$ is $\Bbb{~Z}^{|P|}$.

This should be understood subject to the proviso that, if $P$ is infinite, $\Bbb{~Z}^{|P|}$ is to be interpreted as the infinite sum and not the infinite product (i.e., it only includes sequences $(i_1, i_2, \ldots)$ where all but finitely many of the $i_j$ are zero).

Comment: Per your last sentence, I have a slight preference for "$\bigoplus_{\vert P\vert}\mathbb{Z}$."

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I'm inclined to agree with you. In an ideal world, perhaps we would use $\Bbb{Z}^{\kappa}$ for the $\kappa$-fold product and $\kappa \Bbb{Z}$ for the $\kappa$-fold sum. But that conflicts with the desire to write $2\Bbb{Z}$ for the set of even integers.

Comment: This only names the abstract isomorphism class of $G_P$; you might also want to explicitly name $G_P$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$.